# How to display validation errors about non-input blocks in Slack modals

Tags: slack, slack-api

## Question

I have a Slack [modal](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals) with a `section` block containing an input element.  When a user submits my modal without entering a value in this input, how do I communicate that error to the user?

## My attempt #1: respond with a validation error

Slack's documentation describes how to validate `input` blocks when I receive a `view_submission` event (https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#displaying_errors). But if I return an error for a `section` block containing a `static_select`, then Slack does not display an error message (nor does it close the modal).

## My attempt #2: set the `optional` field to false

`input` blocks have an `optional` field that can be used for validation.  But a `static_select` in a `section` block does not have an `optional` field: https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#select

## My attempt #3: use `input` blocks

I can not use `input` blocks because they do not trigger `block_actions` messages (documented at https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#interactions).  I need to update the modal as the users answer questions.

## My attempt #4: the desperation solution that works

I could reply to the `view_submission` event with a ["response_action": "update"](https://api.slack.com/surfaces/modals/using#updating_views) response.  In that response include an error message like this above the input with the missing value:

```json
{
  "type": "section",
  "text": {
    "type": "mrkdwn",
    "text": "*Please provide a start time:*"
  }
}
```

I do not like this solution because I doubt I can duplicate the nice error messaging UX that Slack provides for `input` block validation.

## Details

Here is a simplified version of the `view` parameter that I am passing to the [views.open](https://api.slack.com/methods/views.open) call:

```
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "block_id": "start_times",
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Choose a start time"
      },
      "accessory": {
        "action_id": "start_times",
        "type": "static_select",
        "placeholder": {
          "type": "plain_text",
          "text": "Choose start"
        },
        "options": [
          {
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "10:27 pm"
            },
            "value":
              "{\"path\":\"bookings/new\",\"date\":\"2020-02-14 04:27:22 UTC\"}"
          },
          {
            "text": {
              "type": "plain_text",
              "text": "10:45 pm"
            },
            "value":
              "{\"path\":\"bookings/new\",\"date\":\"2020-02-14 04:45:00 UTC\"}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "callback_id": "create booking",
  "private_metadata":
    "{\"channel_id\":\"C6M2A4690\",\"min_start_time\":\"2020-02-14 04:27:22 UTC\",\"path\":\"bookings/create\",\"room_id\":175128,\"selected_end_time\":null,\"selected_start_time\":null}",
  "type": "modal",
  "submit": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "Book"
  },
  "title": {
    "type": "plain_text",
    "text": "Booking room"
  }
}
```

If the user immediately clicks submit, this is my response to the `view_submission` event:

```
{
  "response_action": "errors",
  "errors": {
    "start_times": "Please complete this required field"
  }
}
```

Upon receipt of my response, Slack turns off the spinner, leaves the modal open, but does not display an error message. The modal looks exactly the same as when it was first opened via `views.open`.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Did you report it to Slack?

Comment: Sort of.  I gave Slack a laundry list of things I thought need improvement in their modal API.  This was one of them.

Comment: @GabrielDeal Any update on this. I'm facing same issue. Pls help.

Comment: I have no updates. I ended up using my "the desperation solution that works" solution that I described in my answer. I start the error message with the :warning: emoji, which helps draw attention to the error message.

Comment: I have this exact same problem, and nowhere I can find a solution to it. Its sure that slack is informed that there is error, as it does not close the modal. But also not showing the errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you posted your question, the functionality of `input` blocks has changed. [Earlier this month](https://api.slack.com/changelog), the ability for `input` blocks to emit `block_actions` payloads was introduced.

In the [Block Kit reference docs for the `input` block](https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/blocks#input) you can see a new `dispatch_action` parameter. This is a boolean which, when set to true, causes the interactive element inside the `input` block to emit a `block_actions` payload when changed.

Therefore, to answer your question more directly, your #3 solution should now be possible without the caveat that you included. Place the `static_select` inside of an `input` block, and set `dispatch_action` to `true`, like so:

```
{
        "type": "input",
        "dispatch_action": true,
        "element": {
            "type": "static_select",
            "placeholder": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Select an item",
                "emoji": true
            },
            "options": [
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "*this is plain_text text*",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-0"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "*this is plain_text text*",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-1"
                },
                {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "*this is plain_text text*",
                        "emoji": true
                    },
                    "value": "value-2"
                }
            ],
            "action_id": "static_select-action"
        },
        "label": {
            "type": "plain_text",
            "text": "Label",
            "emoji": true
        }
    }
```

Upon receiving a `view_submission` payload, you'll now be able to respond with the correct validation errors and display them to a user. And you can still receive `block_actions` payloads as needed too.

Comment: Also, **text** field must be changed to **label**, and **type** of **label** must be changed to **plain_text** (if text is being used).

Answer (score 0):

Set the response's "`content_type`" to "`application/json`" before returning response.

If you are using Django as backend then you can do this.

```
error_object = {
      "response_action": "errors",
      "errors": {
        "start_times": "Please complete this required field"
      }
    }

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(error_object), content_type="application/json")

   ===OR===

return JsonResponse(error_object)
```

don't forget to import JsonReponse if you are using it:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
```

Comment: That is not my problem. I do set the content type correctly. The validation error response works fine if I use input blocks (a non-interactive input type). It just does not work if I use an interactive component like the one described in my question.